# Huge memory usage in Xilinx Vivado

Tags: xilinx, vivado

Vivado consumes all of the free memory space in my machine during synthesis and for this reason, the machine either hangs or crashes after a while.

I encountered this issue when using Vivado 2018.1 on Windows 10 (w/ 8GB RAM) and Vivado 2020.1 on CentOS 7 (w/ 16GB RAM).

Is there any option in Vivado to limit its memory usage?

Comment: Did you found this info of Xilinx: https://www.xilinx.com/products/design-tools/vivado/memory.html
It depends on which FPGA and the design.  But just to give you an idea, our machines have  118GB and 26 CPU's and we're complaining it is too slow.

Comment: @vermaete  Yes, I looked at that document but synthesizing a design even for Zynq-7000 causes my machine to freeze.

Comment: It depends on the IP blocks that get synthesized. A complex block needs many GBs while simple blocks need much less. Are you synthesizing complex IPs? A non-optimal but very simple trick is to reduce the number of jobs.

Comment: @LucaCeresoli There is no complex or third-party IP in my design.

Comment: Vivado is terrible at multiprocessing.  I have a 64GB, 16-core machine and I rarely go over 3 or 4 GB.  and a few % CPU.  I'm running 2020.1 but it seems no better.   You might want to see what other software is taking up memory on Windows 10.  You'd be surprised how much RAM pressure some IDEs place on it.

Answer (score 1):

If this problem happens when you are synthesizing multiple out of context modules, try reducing the Number of Jobs when you start the run.